# CSS background based graph

Tags: css, background-image

Attempting to make a simple graph with the CSS background property and I am running into an issue I can't wrap my head around.

Using a container of x width and y height inside of which I draw the bars each one 10% of the parent's width (variable height based on data) starting at background position 0% and ending at position 90% I should have 10 bars of equal size that fit the container perfectly yes? Unfortunately that is not the result I see on my page, instead I end up with a container that will hold 11 bars, not 10.

Screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/67967664/Bars.jpg

CSS as follow:

```
background: linear-gradient(hsl(160,50%,20%), hsl(20,50%,20%)) 0% bottom no-repeat,
linear-gradient(hsl(160,50%,20%), hsl(20,50%,20%)) 10% bottom no-repeat,
linear-gradient(hsl(160,50%,20%), hsl(20,50%,20%)) 20% bottom no-repeat,
linear-gradient(hsl(160,50%,20%), hsl(20,50%,20%)) 30% bottom no-repeat,
linear-gradient(hsl(160,50%,20%), hsl(20,50%,20%)) 40% bottom no-repeat,
linear-gradient(hsl(160,50%,20%), hsl(20,50%,20%)) 50% bottom no-repeat,
linear-gradient(hsl(160,50%,20%), hsl(20,50%,20%)) 60% bottom no-repeat,
linear-gradient(hsl(160,50%,20%), hsl(20,50%,20%)) 70% bottom no-repeat,
linear-gradient(hsl(160,50%,20%), hsl(20,50%,20%)) 80% bottom no-repeat,
linear-gradient(hsl(160,50%,20%), hsl(20,50%,20%)) 90% bottom no-repeat hsl(0, 0%, 12%);

background-size: 10% 5%,
                 10% 10%,
                 10% 15%,
                 10% 20%,
                 10% 25%,
                 10% 30%,
                 10% 35%,
                 10% 40%,
                 10% 45%,
                 10% 50%;
```

`background-size` is for testing purposes only, will be set/updated via JavaScript in the final code.

So question is, what am I doing wrong, or not understanding about the methods I am using? to my logic having a bar at position 0% of 10% width would mean it fills the space between 0% and 10% the next go from 10% to 20% .. from 90% to 100%

Using: Firefox 38.0.5 with Stylish 1.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are seeing is because of how `background-position` works in CSS when given as a percentage. The following is what the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position) says about percentage based `background-position`:

> A percentage for the horizontal offset is relative to (width of background positioning area - width of background image). A percentage for the vertical offset is relative to (height of background positioning area - height of background image), where the size of the image is the size given by ‘background-size’.
>
> For example, with a value pair of ‘0% 0%’, the upper left corner of the image is aligned with the upper left corner of, usually, the box's padding edge. A value pair of ‘100% 100%’ places the lower right corner of the image in the lower right corner of the area. **With a value pair of ‘75% 50%’, the point 75% across and 50% down the image is to be placed at the point 75% across and 50% down the area.**

(emphasis is mine)

As stated there, if we specify the position as `10% bottom` (equivalent to `10% 100%`), the background image actually gets placed in such a way that the point that is 10% across on the image is placed at the point 10% across on the containing box.

Now for example , let us assume that the box is 100px x 100px. So 10% on the container box would at 10px and 10% on the image would be at 1px mark on the image (because the background size is set as 10% of container size). So, the image would actually be positioned at 9px inside the container so that 10px on the container and 1px on the image are the same point. This makes the second image to overlap the first image by 1px. Similarly the third image would overlap by the 2nd by 2px and so on.

Rule for calculating position when using multiple background images **of same size** (X-axis), is:

- `background-position` of nth-element = 100% * (n-1) / (total no. of images - 1)

For Y-axis, there is no problem because all of them are positioned at 100% and so the bottom of the image will match with the bottom of the container.

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(hsl(160, 50%, 20%), hsl(20, 50%, 20%)) 0% bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(hsl(160, 50%, 20%), hsl(20, 50%, 20%)) 11.11% bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(hsl(160, 50%, 20%), hsl(20, 50%, 20%)) 22.22% bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(hsl(160, 50%, 20%), hsl(20, 50%, 20%)) 33.33% bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(hsl(160, 50%, 20%), hsl(20, 50%, 20%)) 44.44% bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(hsl(160, 50%, 20%), hsl(20, 50%, 20%)) 55.55% bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(hsl(160, 50%, 20%), hsl(20, 50%, 20%)) 66.66% bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(hsl(160, 50%, 20%), hsl(20, 50%, 20%)) 77.77% bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(hsl(160, 50%, 20%), hsl(20, 50%, 20%)) 88.88% bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(hsl(160, 50%, 20%), hsl(20, 50%, 20%)) 99.99% bottom no-repeat hsl(0, 0%, 12%);
  background-size: 10% 5%, 10% 10%, 10% 15%, 10% 20%, 10% 25%, 10% 30%, 10% 35%, 10% 40%, 10% 45%, 10% 50%;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I will accept this answer for the time being, although I still find the way it is laid out to be highly counter-intuitive, thank you.

Comment: @EntarraDe'Lacord: Absolutely true, it is very counter-intuitive but it is as per spec and there is no proposed change in the newer versions. So I guess we have to live with it.